# Simulink battery model with buck converter

Tags: current, pwm, switching

I have created this model in simulink:

[image]

Vfc and Rfc are the equivalent of a battery, and the battery is connected to a load R, through a buck converter. The buck converter is implemented with a mosfet, and an LC filter. For the time being I am switching the mosfet from a pulse generator. My problem is that I cannot find a way to stabilize the current on the battery side of the circuit. Obviously due to switching, the current is a pulse.I tried adding a capacitor in parallel with Vfc,Rfc, but it did not work. Here is the current and voltage waveform(scope2):

[image]

My question is, firstly, why is current like a sawtooth waveform and not like a pulse waveform? Also, more importantly, how can I make the current as steady as possible?

Here are the values of the components:

1. Ideal Switches
2. Vfc=42.2 V
3. Rfc=0.346 Ω
4. L=200e-6 H
5. C=500e-6 F
6. R=10 Ω
7. Switching Frequency=10KHz
8. Duty Cycle=50%

   EDIT: By increasing L, sawtooth waveform becomes pulse waveform. Thanks for the suggestion in the comments. Any ideas for the second question? How can I have stable (DC) current on the battery side of the circuit?

Comment: Because discontinuous conduction mode (DCM). Increase the inductance.

Comment: It's a sawtooth wave because your inductor prevents any instantaneous change in current. Like winny said, increase the inductance and you should be able to have a cleaner current. Or increase the switching frequency, I think that would work too.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I tried increasing the inductance. The result was that the current became a pulse waveform. It still is pulses however, from zero to a certain point. Any ideas for the second part of my question? How can I  stabilize the current (I mean, have DC current) on the battery side of the circuit?

Comment: A buck converter has discontinuous input current.  When the top switch turns off, there's no current delivered from the battery.  When it's on, the inductor current flows from the battery.  The best you can do is put lots of capacitance on the input.  Getting to DC is a stretch though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By its very nature, the current a switching regulator draws is pulsed.  You can't change that.

If you want to keep that pulsed current from disturbing other parts of your circuit, then you need to use a filter.

The idea with the capacitor was good, but you didn't quite do it right.

What you did was this (where U1 represents your switching regulator:)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqEj38.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

No matter how large a capacitor you use for C1, you will still be measuring the pulses that the switching regulator draws.

What you needed was this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fseNnm.png)</sup>

This will filter out the pulses from the switching regulator so that AM1 (ampere meter) will measure a smooth current flow.  VM1 (voltage meter) will also show a steady voltage - more to the point, it will show a voltage that slowly changes in response to changes in the load.

Values for Rf and Cf depend on the following:

1. Switching frequency
2. Load

Any low pass filter calculator on the internet can help you figure Rf and Cf - but, those assume that the load is pretty much zero (open circuit.)

You would choose Rf to be much lower than RL (preferably like 1/10 of RL.)  Then you decide the cutoff of the filter.  Since you are using 10kHz as the switching frequency, a cutoff of 1kHz would be a good starting point.

Now, take Rf and the cutoff frequency and use a low pass filter calculator ([like this one](https://electronicbase.net/low-pass-filter-calculator/#rc-low-pass-how-it-works)) to calculate the needed capacitance.

Put the values that you calculate for R and C into Rf and Cf and see how well it cleans up the pulses at AM1.

For a load of 10 ohms (as in your example,) I took Rf = 1 ohm and the cutoff as 1 kHz.  I came up with 160µF.

I didn't simulate it because I don't feel like trying to duplicate your switching circuit using the simulator here on the site.

It shouldn't be too difficult for you to modify your simulated circuit, though.  It's really just adding a couple of passive parts in the right place - and being sure you are measuring what you meant to measure.

---

I am not an electrical engineer.  The suggestions are pretty much just "eyeballed" (I took numbers that seemed like they ought to fit.)

Try it out.  If it helps (and it should,) then you could ask another question about how to properly calculate the filter and dimension the parts so that it works well.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that out. Everything worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing that the root of the problem is more the internal series resistance of the battery. Using a battery with a higher A/hr rating may help more than adding more input side capacitance. If you think about it, putting a capacitor across a battery is just adding a short term battery to a long term one. 
As @ Felthry had mentioned, I agree that going to a substantially higher frequency switcher might give you the best results. A larger battery with a lower internal resistance will also help.
One last important point is: are you using a standard capacitor or a low ESR (Equivalent Series Resistance) capacitor in your LC filter? If not The Panasonic FM series capacitors are perfect for switchers. The number one failure I see in monitors and TV's is bad capacitors in the output of the switcher. The cause is cheap capacitors that do not have a low enough ESR.

Comment: It is a simulated battery consisting of an ideal voltage source in series with a resistor.  Your suggestion misses the entire base of the question.

Comment: My Blonde roots are showing.